# Changing currency in Broadleaf commerce

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to change change currency symbol that appears throughtout broadleaf application.

Exploring the code I found that  BLC has a thymleaf dialect 'blc' and and attribute 'price' to render price/cost in web pages.

Example:

```
<div style="font: 32px/28px 'Oxygen', Helvetica, sans-serif;" blc:price="${order.total}"></div>
```

Reffering to '**org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.processor.PriceTextDisplayProcessor**' class , the overriden method getText seems to be returning '$' sign with the price :-

```
    if (price == null || price.isZero()) {
        return "$0.00";
    } else {
        return "$" + price.getAmount().toString();
    }
```

Doubts :-

1. Where are the spring beans defined for BLC dialect and processor? How the blc dialect is actually   configured and how can I configure my own processor for price attribute.
2. How 'Currency Resolution' is connected with this [See here](http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/2.2/Currency-Resolution.html)
3. Any quick workaround for this problem.

Please correct me if I am missing any information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kumar,

You will want to upgrade to Broadleaf Commerce 2.2 where the PriceTextDisplayProcessor was enhanced to handle currency formatting.

Information on your other questions:

- Broadleaf Commerce provides a set of Thymeleaf Processors collectively known as a BLCDialect.   Most are defined in [this file on Github](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/blob/master/core/broadleaf-framework-web/src/main/resources/bl-framework-web-applicationContext.xml)
- Creating your own thymeleaf dialect to use with BLC is discussed [here](http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/2.2/Merge-Configuration.html).
- In 2.2, the key mechanism for setting locale (and generally currency as a result) happens with the [BroadleafRequestProcessor](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/blob/BroadleafCommerce-2.2.x/common/src/main/java/org/broadleafcommerce/common/web/BroadleafRequestProcessor.java)

Support for multiple currencies is achieved via the Price List feature that is part of the Broadleaf Commerce commercial module.   Showing a single currency can be done using the steps above or perhaps more simply in your case by writing your own Thymeleaf Processor.

Comment: Thanks. I solved by creating my own dialect and processor and replacing blc:price by <my_dialect>:price in HTMLs.